# Method 'map' was called on null when I try to clean the stream

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stream which feeds a list of items typed as 'Client'. I have too a search bar which the user writes some name and the list should filter the results as searched and when Click at other button named 'clear' it should reset the list to default. So, I have wrote these methods:

```dart
//called when tap search button (if it has a text typed)
  void setSearch(String search) {
    _search = search;
    _streamController.add(null);//the error throws here
    load(clean: true);
  }

//called when tap 'clear' button
  void clearSearch() {
    _search = '';
    _offset = 1;
    _clients.clear();
    _streamController.stream.drain();
    _streamController.add(null); //the error throws here
    load(clean: true);
  }
```

But when I tap search or clear it throws this error:

> Receiver: null. NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null. Tried calling: map(Closure: (Map<dynamic, dynamic>) => Client)

How can I handle this? there is another way to clean the stream? If you need more code I can update the question

**UPDATE**
This is my build method

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 60.0,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 3,
              child: Container(
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: AppColorSecondary,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: AppColorSecondary,),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColorSecondary),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: AppColorPrimary,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        searchController.clear();
                        clientsController.loadMore();
                      },
                      child: FittedBox(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                        child: IconTheme(
                          data: IconThemeData(),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.clear,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  controller: searchController,
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    clientsController.setSearch(searchController.text);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: clientsController.stream,
              builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.error != null) {
                  print(snapshot.error.toString());
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                  );
                } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('0clients'),
                  );
                } else {
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: clientsController.refresh,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: scrollController,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                        if (i < snapshot.data.length) {
                          return ClientsWidget(snapshot.data[i]);
                        } else if (clientsController.hasMore) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32.0),
                            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a event to you streamController? in there you can set the search to clear. And maybe make an inline if statement where you have the map to show a empty placeholder

Comment: Could you write an answer with a example? I'm not understanding properly

Comment: I see now that I was wrong, sorry. I am used to bloc and that handles the .add function different. But cant you set the search to the default value? So give the stream the default instead of null?

Comment: If there is a way to do it I don't know

Comment: How do you handle the data that comes from stream?

Comment: I have a StreamBuilder with the stream values

Comment: I meant add some code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232699/discussion-between-helloworldd-and-silkenl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `_streamController.add([]);`